# Repainted wall is peeling

Tags: walls, paint

So I painted my wall because it was peeling and my wall now looks like this and yes the paint I put on the peeling spots are dry please Help!!  [image]

Comment: looks like there is a water problem behind that wall that needs looking at,

Comment: Did you paint over not-yet-cured drywall patch (spackle)?

Comment: Was the paint only pealing in the spots, did you touch the spots to see if the wall was soft or damp?

Comment: This looks like some drywall mud was applied to the wall and then never primed before it was painted. You should be able to follow @machavity's response below and get desirable results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's something causing damp on the walls - which is most likely why the old paint was peeling in the first place.

Ideally you need to track down what's causing this in the first place (take it from me these things don't just get better on their own!) - if you can't track this down though or the issue isn't something that is going to get worse or cause other problems you could try coating the wall with some [damp sealant paint](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Interior-Damp-Seal---White-1L/p/600317) and re-painting over that.

Comment: That's probably not moisture (too spotty), but something oily the wall absorbed previously (some old types of wallpaper glue could do this)

Answer (score 1):

I would go buy some oil-based (mineral spirit cleanup) primer (Kilz Original, Cover Stain, etc). It will stink like crazy, but it should adhere to those spots fairly well and block them from damaging any paint you put over them.